# What is the best way to split a string to get all the substrings by Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

For example, the words "stack", I want to get an array like:

```
['s', 'st', 'sta', ... 'stack', 't', 'ta', ... , 'c', 'ck', 'k']
```

I did this by such code:

```
def split_word(str)
  result = []
  chas = str.split("")
  len = chas.size
  (0..len-1).each do |i|
    (i..len-1).each do |j|
      result.push(chas[i..j].join)
    end
  end
  result.uniq
end
```

Is there better and clean way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: general advice: better use map (functional) instead of following the pattern "init empty + iterate + push + return" (imperative)

Comment: @tokland: What you are describing is not a *map* (`collect` in Ruby), it's a *fold* or more generally a *catamorphism* (`inject` or `reduce` in Ruby).

Comment: @Jörg, the pattern I was talking about is not a fold: "a = []; [1,2,3].each { |x| a << 2*x }; a" vs "[1,2,3].map { |x| 2*x }". See my solution, this problem can be solved with two maps + a flatten (concat) in a purely functional way.

Comment: well, a map can always be written as a fold... anyway, leaving terms aside I hope the example in the previous comment shows my intent. The problem is of type, in Haskell terms, "a -> [a]", so a map seems the most natural solution to me.

Comment: @tokland: Well, a `map` is just a special case of a `fold` :-) Basically, `map f = foldr (λx y → f x : y) []`. The general description you gave in your comment describes the general case of a `fold`, but for the specific example you are right, this is of course a `map`. In particular, when `init empty` is a collection of the same type as the original one and `iterate` is just applying a transformation function, and `push` puses *all* elements, then it is a `map`. Actually, `fold` is general: *any* iteration (`map`, `select`, `count` etc., even `each`) can be expressed as a `fold`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def split_word s
  (0..s.length).inject([]){|ai,i|
    (1..s.length - i).inject(ai){|aj,j|
      aj << s[i,j]
    }
  }.uniq
end
```

And you can also consider using [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/Set.html) instead of Array for the result.

PS: Here's another idea, based on array product:

```
def split_word s
  indices = (0...s.length).to_a
  indices.product(indices).reject{|i,j| i > j}.map{|i,j| s[i..j]}.uniq
end
```

Comment: fixed second solution after a suggestion from user @steel

Comment: the output should be a, b, c, ab, bc, ac, abc

Answer (score 10):

I'd write:

```
def split_word(s)
  0.upto(s.length - 1).flat_map do |start| 
    1.upto(s.length - start).map do |length| 
      s[start, length]
    end
  end.uniq
end

groups = split_word("stack")
# ["s", "st", "sta", "stac", "stack", "t", "ta", "tac", "tack", "a", "ac", "ack", "c", "ck", "k"]
```

It's usually more clear and more compact to use `map` (functional) instead of the pattern *init empty + each + append + return* (imperative).

Comment: Yes, you are right tokland. I prefer functional pattern than imperative pattern too. Thanks for your suggestion! And which pattern do you think has the better performance?

Comment: @pake007: well, I said that it's usually faster, but here I wound't be so sure because of the flatten and the non-laziness of Ruby's arrays. Anyway, don't sweat for performance, the difference is probably minimal.

Comment: Is flat_map necessary? If so, what cases is flat_map needed for? I ask because substituting flat_map with map produces the same result

Comment: @kraftydevil Without flat_map, you should get a nested array. The rule of a list-comprehension: use flat_map in all the iterations but the last one.

Answer (score 7):

```
def substrings(str)
  output = []
  (0...str.length).each do |i|
    (i...str.length).each do |j|
      output << str[i..j]
    end
  end
  output
end
```

this is just a cleaned up version of your method and it works with less steps =)

Answer (score 3):

Don't think so.

Here's my attempted version:

```
def split_word(str)
  length = str.length - 1
  [].tap do |result|
    0.upto(length) do |i|
      length.downto(i) do |j|
        substring = str[i..j]
        result << substring unless result.include?(substring)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def substrings(str)
  (0...str.length).map do |i|
     (i...str.length).each { |j| str[i..j]}
  end
end
```

Just another way to do it, that reads a little clearer to me.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the recursive way to get all the possible sub strings.

```
def substrings str
  return [] if str.size < 1
  ((0..str.size-1).map do |pos|
    str[0..pos]
  end) + substrings(str[1..])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Way later, but this is what I got from reformatting your code a bit.

```
def substrings(string)
  siz = string.length
  answer = []

  (0..siz-1).each do |n|
    (n..siz-1).each do |i|
      answer << string[n..i]
    end
  end
  answer
end
```