# Palindrome count in a string

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm, palindrome

So, I explored www.hackerearth.com today and was solving my first problem statement in ruby: http://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/palindrome-count-1/

**Palindrome count Problem**:

Given a string S, count the number of non empty sub strings that are palindromes.
A sub string is any continuous sequence of characters in the string.
A string is said to be palindrome, if the reverse of the string is same as itself.
Two sub strings are different if they occur at different positions in S

**Input**: Input contains only a single line that contains string S.

**Output**: Print a single number, the number of sub strings that are palindromes.

**Constraints**

1 <= |S| <= 50

S contains only lower case latin letters, that is characters a to z.

**Sample Input (Plaintext Link)**: dskjkd
**Sample Output (Plaintext Link)**: 7

**Explanation** -

The 7 sub strings are d, s, k, j, k, d, kjk.

Time limit 3 sec(s)

Memory limit 256 MB

Source limit 1024 KB

**Here is what I did:**

```
chars = gets.chomp.gsub(' ', '').split('')
counts = chars.count
(2..chars.count).each do |len|
  chars.combination(len).each do |comb|
    string = comb.inject(:<<)
    counts += 1 if string.reverse == string
  end
end
puts counts
```

However, this approach seems to be inefficient in terms of the time execution and memory usage. Is there any way to optimize this? Or have any other approach to this solution, algorithm is also welcome as solution! Thanks.

**Edit**

Since, all the answers are correct. I had to choose the one which is efficient. So, I ran benchmark and here is the result: https://gist.github.com/suryart/7577481

Based on the result you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104428/palindrome-count-in-a-string/20104880#20104880) is much faster. Thank you for the new approaches/ solution guys! :)

Comment: The main reason your code is relatively slow is that, by using [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) you are checking many combinations of characters that are not consecutive. For example, `['p', 'o', 'p'].combination(2).to_a # => [["p","o"],["p","p"],["o","p"]`, which would lead to you concluding that "pp" is a palendrome, That's true, but it's not a substring of "pop". This is a misuse of `combination`.  There are other problems that I'll address in a separate comment.

Comment: If I run your code with "pop" and insert `p string` before `count +1..`, it shows you are checking to see if "po", "pop", "op" and "popopp" are palendromes.  What testing did you do?  I'd also like to point out that exercises like this one are intended to improve your understanding of Ruby's power and expressiveness.  If you focus on speed alone, there's no point in using Ruby.  Instead stick to C (disguised as Ruby in some of the answers).

Comment: Nice catch @CarySwoveland I couldn't have possibly find it out. Thank you so much for pointing this out. I'll remember to not to use combination on such occasions from now on. I thought that each combination will be required to see if the string and sub strings are palindrome or not. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the algorithm to get all subsets of the string from [What is the best way to split a string to get all the substrings by Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508096/what-is-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-to-get-all-the-substrings-by-ruby)

```
count = 0

(0..len-1).each do |i|
  (i..len-1).each do |j|
    temp = s[i..j]
    count = count + 1 if temp == temp.reverse
  end
end
puts "found #{count} palindromes"
```

Comment: Your solution is much faster than rest of the others, including mine. :)

Comment: @Surya did you implement my algorithm? I am pretty sure that it will beat G_A's.

Answer (score 2):

This approach -- in pseudo-code -- should work.

```
input: String s

// each single letter is palindrome itself
palindromsCount = length(s)

// let count all odd-length palindromes first (palindrome of length 1 already counted)
// we will be checking from the very middle of a sub-string, if it is symmetric 
for(int i = 1; i < length(s)-1; i++)
   for(int j = 1; ; j++)
       if (i - j < 0 || i + j >= length(s) || s[i-j] != s[i+j])
          break
       else
          palindromsCount += 1

// let count in similar way all even-length palindromes
for(int i = 0; i < length(s)-1; i++)
   for(int j = 0; ; j++)
       if (i - j < 0 || i + j + 1 >= length(s) || s[i-j] != s[i+j+1])
          break
       else
          palindromsCount += 1
```

**EDIT** Of course both loops can be combined into a single one -- I did not want to do it for better readability.

Comment: I appreciate the algorithm. But, you seems to have four loops iterations. Don't you think it will increase the complexity of the code and time execution, as I have done in my code? Just asking. :)

Comment: @Surya Actually the very number of loops (in most cases) do not matter much from the theoretical point of view. For practical reasons: I am 99% sure that it is impossible to bit my solution. Here is why: 1) Making use of symmetry of a palindrome, I do not consider all possible  sub-strings 2) I do not create any new objects (as e.g. substring.reverse). For a `string` with only trivial palindromes (1-letter-long) my algorithm will work in O(n).

Comment: I'll try to convert it in code. Though I didn't understand the part where you loop for odd and even occurrence of string characters to see the palindrome. Could you please tell me the steps you were trying to follow in this algorithm?

Comment: @Surya The middle of a palindrome is a mirror -- if you go n steps to the right or n steps to the left (from the middle) you have to found exactly the same letter. Moreover if a substring `s` is contained in some longer substring `S` [once we have centered their *middles* -- e.g. `aba` and `cabad`, but not `abc` and `cabad`] and `s` is not a palindrome so neither is `S`.

Comment: What about a string like: `cababad`? there are multiple palindrome sub strings. In your case the check on a string moves on char by char each time?

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable#each_cons](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) is handy here:

```
str = "momanddadpaddledthekayak"

b = str.chars
(1..b.size).reduce(0) {|t,n| t + b.each_cons(n).reduce(0) \
  {|r,e| w = e.join; w==w.reverse ? r + 1 : r}} # => 30
```

If we want to see the palendromes:

```
b = str.chars
pals = (1..b.size).each_with_object([]) {|n, a| b.each_cons(n).each \
  {|e| w = e.join; a << w if w==w.reverse}}

p pals.size # => 30
p pals #  => ["m", "o", "m", "a", "n", "d", "d", "a", "d", "p", "a",\
              "d", "d", "l", "e", "d", "t", "h", "e", "k", "a", "y",
              "a", "k", "dd", "dd", "mom", "dad", "aya", "kayak"]
```

Edit: @squiguy made the useful observation that we may not want to count duplicates. If that's the case, my first calculation above could not be used and the second would have to be changed as squiguy suggests (e.g., `p a.uniq.size`) or changed to build a hash rather than an array:

```
b = str.chars
pals = (1..b.size).each_with_object({}) {|n,h| b.each_cons(n).each \
  {|e| w = e.join; h[w] = 0 if w==w.reverse}}.keys

p pals.size # => 17
p pals# => ["m", "o", "a", "n", "d", "p", "l", "e", "t",\
            "h", "k", "y", "dd", "mom", "dad", "aya", "kayak"]
```

[Edit: replaced `each` with `each_with_object`. On rereading the question, it appears that dups are to be counted.]

Comment: You might consider using `.uniq` if there aren't supposed to be any duplicates ('dd').