# How to take a random slice of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, random, slice

If I have a string like `'Lorem Ipsum'`, I need a method, which returns a random part of the string, like `'rem I'`, `'Lor'`, etc. (**UPDATE**: the method should not return empty strings). So far I have come up with this:

```
def random_slice string
  start = rand string.size - 2
  finish = rand start + 1..string.size - 1
  word[start..finish]
end
```

Are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write it simpler with:

```
s[rand(s.length), rand(s.length - 1) + 1]
```

Comment: may return empty string too.

Comment: Why did you change your answer? It was better before.

Comment: @sawa - Change to the first argument: for string '12345678910' the previous version would never return '0'. Change to the second param - second param cannot be zero to prevent empty strings being returned.

Comment: Why does empty string have to be prevented?

Comment: @sawa - The method showed in the question does not return any empty string.

Comment: @sawa - actually it also not returning any 1-character-long strings as well. I just assume it shouldn't return empty strings, but agree it wasn't clarified in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [String#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-slice) method.

```
s = 'Lorem Ipsum'
s.slice(rand(s.size), rand(s.size) + 1)
=> "orem Ip"
```

> If passed a start index and a length, returns a substring containing
>   length characters starting at the index.

Comment: may return empty string.

Comment: I would not accept this as a random substring. For all `x > y` in `s.slice(x, y)`, it yields empty string. That will result about 1/3 ~ 1/2 of all results being empty string.

Comment: it was just to illustrate how the method is used. I'm sure he is smart enough to figure out what the good params are.

Comment: @toro2k Ah, I see. I took a bad try on my machine and made a wrong assumption. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Just made a simple benchmark of the randomness of the accepted answer:

```
s = "0123456789"
count = Hash.new(0)
SAMPLE_SIZE = 5000000

SAMPLE_SIZE.times do
  sub = s[rand(s.length), rand(s.length - 1) + 1]
  count[sub] += 1
end

count.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.each do |k, v|
  puts "#{k.ljust(10)} #{v.to_f*100/SAMPLE_SIZE}%"
end
```

The results are:

```
9          9.9888%
89         8.87602%
789        7.79196%
6789       6.66138%
56789      5.5665%
456789     4.45512%
3456789    3.32218%
23456789   2.2117%
23456      1.12276%
123456789  1.1204%
...        # all about 1% for the others
```

It's generally not a random solution. We can prove that the actual result follows this trend (assume that `rand` generates real random values).

A more random one would be:

1. generate all possible substrings into an array, as pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508096).
2. call `Array#sample`. You can cache the result from the first step and do step 2 multiple times.

Maybe the accepted answer just met the requirements, and it's really simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "Lorem ipsum your text goes here"
boundaries = [rand(str.size), rand(str.size)].sort
p str[Range.new(*boundaries)] # => "rem ipsum your"
```