# Ruby search for word in string

Tags: ruby, string

Given `input = "helloworld"`

The output should be `output = ["hello", "world"]`

Given I have a method called `is_in_dict?` which returns true if there's a word given

So far i tried:

```
ar = []
input.split("").each do |f|
  ar << f if is_in_dict? f
  // here need to check given char
end
```

How to achieve it in Ruby?

Comment: so do u need all combinations like [ "hell" , "hello" , "world" ]

Comment: Give proper input to your code and then expect the _output_..

Comment: @Orion yes you're right, could you share some code

Comment: You're looking at each individual character, so none of them will be a word. Try checking all substrings of the input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508096/what-is-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-to-get-all-the-substrings-by-ruby

Comment: Can you access the dictionary, i.e. do you have an array of words?

Comment: What is that regex followed by text?

Comment: I assume you are not looking for all substrings of `input` that are in the dictionary, as most dictionaries include the words "low" and "or", yet they are not included in your desired output. Perhaps you mean the elements of `ar` are to be substrings that appear at the beginning or end of `input` and are in the dictionary. Please edit to clarify. @sawa: lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting the input into characters, you have to inspect all combinations, i.e. `"h"`, `"he"`, `"hel"`, ... `"helloworld"`, `"e"`, `"el"` , `"ell"`, ... `"elloworld"` and so on.

Something like this should work:

```
(0..input.size).to_a.combination(2).each do |a, b|
  word = input[a...b]
  ar << word if is_in_dict?(word)
end
#=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
ar
#=> ["hello", "world"]
```

Or, using [`each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), which returns the array:

```
(0..input.size).to_a.combination(2).each_with_object([]) do |(a, b), array|
  word = input[a...b]
  array << word if is_in_dict?(word)
end
#=> ["hello", "world"]
```

Another approach is to build a custom [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerator.html):

```
class String
  def each_combination
    return to_enum(:each_combination) unless block_given?

    (0..size).to_a.combination(2).each do |a, b|
      yield self[a...b]
    end
  end
end
```

`String#each_combination` yields all combinations (instead of just the indices):

```
input.each_combination.to_a
#=> ["h", "he", "hel", "hell", "hello", "hellow", "hellowo", "hellowor", "helloworl", "helloworld", "e", "el", "ell", "ello", "ellow", "ellowo", "ellowor", "elloworl", "elloworld", "l", "ll", "llo", "llow", "llowo", "llowor", "lloworl", "lloworld", "l", "lo", "low", "lowo", "lowor", "loworl", "loworld", "o", "ow", "owo", "owor", "oworl", "oworld", "w", "wo", "wor", "worl", "world", "o", "or", "orl", "orld", "r", "rl", "rld", "l", "ld", "d"]
```

It can be used with [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to easily filter specific words:

```
input.each_combination.select { |word| is_in_dict?(word) }
#=> ["hello", "world"]
```

Comment: You may show also the OP how to use `map` instead of `each`+`<<` (and use do/end for multiline blocks)

Comment: @tokland I've changed `{ … }` to `do … end` and added an example with `each_with_object` as `map` would require another `compact` call.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a task for recursion. In short you want to take letters one by one until you get a word which is in dictionary. This however will not guarantee that the result is correct, as the remaining letters may not form a words ('hell' + 'oworld'?). This is what I would do:

```
def split_words(string)
  return [[]] if string == ''
  chars = string.chars
  word = ''
  (1..string.length).map do 
    word += chars.shift
    next unless is_in_dict?(word)
    other_splits = split_words(chars.join)
    next if other_splits.empty?
    other_splits.map {|split| [word] + split }
  end.compact.inject([], :+)
end

split_words('helloworld')    #=> [['hello', 'world']]   No hell!
```

It will also give you all possible splits, so pages with urls like [penisland](http://www.penisland.net/) can be avoided

```
split_words('penisland')  #=> [['pen', 'island'], [<the_other_solution>]]
```