# Regular Express Contains part of word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

So I have few words which needs to be matched using Regular Expression.

```
steve jobs
steve
bill gates
mark
stevejobs
```

And now I want to look for all names which contains part of this string `stevejobs`

So now I should get `steve jobs`, `steve` and `stevejobs`

I can achieve this using this expression `steve(?:jobs?)?`

But my code doesn't know to split a word into two names i.e. from `stevejobs` to `steve` and `jobs`

So the word can be anything, it might be `ntechi` and will match `technology`, `technical` as `tech` is part of both the words.

Can this be done??

Comment: If your word is `ntechi` do you want it to match `chat` because there is a `ch` in both of them? If so, then you can look at permutations...

Comment: Yes it will match `chat`, but word like `coh` will not be matched as `c` and `h` are not together

Comment: So any substring of 2 or more characters?

Answer (score 0):

After working through the comments it appears you are looking for a match of any substring 2 or more characters.  So ntechi would match chat because of the ch.

Since any substring of more than 2 is actually made up of multiple substrings of 2, we just have to go through all substrings of 2:

```
$mylist = array(
    'steve jobs',
    'steve',
    'bill gates',
    'mark',
    'stevejobs'
);
for ($j = 0; $j < count($mylist); $j++)
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str)-1); $i++)
        if (strstr(substr($str, $i, $i+1), $mylist[$j])) {
            echo $mylist[$j]." contains ".substr($str, $i, $i+1);
            break; // this will keep the same one from being reported multiple times
        }
```

Unfortunately this won't tell you the longest match, but it will list the items from your array that match.

Oh, my apologies - I just noticed you are using ruby-on-rails rather than PHP. Hopefully you can treat the PHP code as pseudo-code and translate it into ruby.

Comment: My words will be dynamic, its not fixed to `stevejobs`. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Um, why the down-vote? The question was how to divide a string arbitrarily according to knowledge known only to people who are in the given culture and my answer was that it can't be done.

Comment: Not by me, person who did it needs to add comment

Comment: Hmmm this worked, but still I need to modify your code. ders no other way of doing it using regex?
Cause the loop will take long time to execute and I have pages with text where I ll find some names from a synonym word

Comment: You could loop through the word and substr out every 2 chars and concatenate them together with ¦ to form a single regex.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know where to split up the string you can only search for strings matching any possible substring. It might be a good idea to set a minimum length such that you don't just include "bill gates" because it contains the substring "e". You could order your matches by the matched substring length - the longer the matching substring, the better the match.

To start with, you find some functions returning all substrings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508096/what-is-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-to-get-all-the-substrings-by-ruby).

Comment: Yaa I guess that is the only thing which will work. But how do I check for substring using regular exp??

Comment: Well, a nice rubyish method would be `"stevejobs".include? "jobs" => true`.

Comment: Of course not. It's not a substring so it returns false correctly. You need one method to get all substrings and then check if they are contained.