# How to split a sentence into multiple parts in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, split

I want to split a main string and create multiples strings with the words obtained in Ruby.

```
str = "one two three four five"
```

I want to create all these possibilities in an array of strings:

```
"one"
"one two"
"one two three"
"one two three four" 
"one two three four five"
```

but also:

```
"two three four five"
"three four five"
"four five"
"five"
```

Ideally I would also obtain the strings inside too, but not required:

```
"two three four"
"two three"
"three four"
```

I tried many things but difficult to have a best way to do that.

For example, I tried to work with each_slice:

```
words = string.split(" ")
        number_of_words = words.length
        max_number_of_slices = number_of_words
        array_of_strings_to_match = []
        number_of_slices = 1
        while (number_of_slices <= max_number_of_slices)
          array = words.each_slice(number_of_slices).map do |a| a.join ' ' end
          array.each do |w| array_of_strings_to_match << w end
          number_of_slices = number_of_slices + 1
        end
```

But it's not the good way.

Any idea is welcome. :-)

This question is a little different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508096) because I need to split a sentence of words, not a string by letters (even if it's quite the same).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to split a string to get all the substrings by Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508096/what-is-the-best-way-to-split-a-string-to-get-all-the-substrings-by-ruby)

Comment: If I run the solution to the proposed dup, calling it as `split_word(str.split)`, I believe that gives your desired output

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
str = "one two three four five".split
1.upto(str.size).flat_map { |i| str.each_cons(i).to_a }

#⇒ [["one"], ["two"], ["three"], ["four"], ["five"],
#   ["one", "two"], ["two", "three"], ["three", "four"], ["four", "five"],
#   ["one", "two", "three"], ["two", "three", "four"], ["three", "four", "five"],
#   ["one", "two", "three", "four"], ["two", "three", "four", "five"], 
#   ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]]
```

Comment: This is actually a much nicer solution to the one I modified. +1

Comment: This is an elegant solution ! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4508269/1954610):

```
def split_words(string)
  words = string.split
  (0..words.length).inject([]) do |ai,i|
    (1..words.length - i).inject(ai) { |aj,j| aj << words[i,j] }
  end.map { |words| words.join(' ') }.uniq
end
```

Usage

```
str = "one two three four five"

split_words(str)
#=> ["one",
#    "one two",
#    "one two three",
#    "one two three four",
#    "one two three four five",
#    "two",
#    "two three",
#    "two three four",
#    "two three four five",
#    "three",
#    "three four",
#    "three four five",
#    "four",
#    "four five",
#    "five"]
```

Comment: Thanks Tom for this modified version. I didn't matched the refered post. I will accept the other solution from mudasobwa.